# How do I turn on word wrap for Output View in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I'm running my code using the extension "Code Runner" and would like the output to be displayed word-wrapped. Currently when I run it, it displays the output all in a single line even if it's a long line.

I tried the setting `"editor.wordWrap": "on"`.

This is how the output and editor look like:

[image: This is how the output and editor look like:]

Comment: I think it's related more to the console/terminal settings than with VS Code (AFAIK, there is no wrap settings for the Output/Terminal pane). Judging from your screenshot, are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, i am on ubuntu

Answer (score 34):

Try adding this to your settings:

```
"[Log]": {
  "editor.wordWrap": "on"
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer to your question @paula-rodrigues

Comment: I have the same issue. This setting (`editor.wordwrap`) only applies to the editor. It does not affect the output window. I'm compiling some template c++ code and the compiler output goes to that window. It results in incredibly long lines some times.

Comment: @DeltA make sure you have `[Log]` in your setting.

Comment: @Diogo-Rocha Yeah, that was it. It was configured not to wrap. Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't this in the settings ui (or is it and I can't find it)?

Answer (score 4):

You can instead use the [built-in debugger configuration for Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) and set in launch configuration to use the `"internalConsole"`

```
{
    "name": "run-test-py",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myfile.py",
    "console": "internalConsole"
},
```

so that the output appears in the **Debug Console** panel. The word wrapping for that panel is controlled by the **Debug > Console: Word Wrap** setting:

[image: vscode setting]

Set it to `true`:

```
"debug.console.wordWrap": false,
```

[image: debug console]

Answer (score 0):

For the Debug Console you can use `"debug.console.wordWrap": false,//default:true` which was added in June 2019 with issue [72210](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72210)

Answer (score 0):

#### VS Code 1.86+ answer

Toggling word wrapping in the Output View is now supported via the `View: Toggle Word Wrap` command when the Output View is focused. That command is bound by default to <kbd>alt/opt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

#### Pre-1.86 answer

Output Channels can have an associated [language mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) (see `createOutputChannel(name: string, languageId?: string): OutputChannel` in [the extension API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api)), but most of them use the other function overload, `createOutputChannel(name: string, options: {log: true}): LogOutputChannel`, which uses the specially defined ["log" language mode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/log). What you need to do is find out what language mode is being used in the output channels of interest, and then override the `editor.wordWrap` setting just for those languages.

To handle the basic cases of the "log" language mode, try putting something akin to the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"[log][Log]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
}
```

You can add other language modes to the above list as needed. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings.

Other related source code for the `log`/`Log` language mode IDs for when VS Code uses them can be found in relation to [src/vs/workbench/services/output/common/output.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/services/output/common/output.ts), where `OUTPUT_MODE_ID` and `LOG_MODE_ID` are defined. Also interesting is the fact that their language support extension defines `Log` as an alias of `log`, but they are registered separately in [src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/browser/output.contribution.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/contrib/output/browser/output.contribution.ts), which I think is why in my experience, you need to specify `"[log][Log]":` instead of just `"[log]":` in the language override setting.

Answer (score 0):

As of vscode v1.86 the command

```
View: Toggle Word Wrap
```

will, when the Output view is focused toggle word wrap on/off.  So you could set up a keybinding like:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+z",                             // appears to be the default keybinding
  "command": "editor.action.toggleWordWrap"
},
```