# Is there a way to toggle word wrapping for the Output window in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, customization

I've been working with large print statements in VS Code recently and was wondering: is there was an easy way to turn on word wrapping in the OUTPUT window rather than having to use a horizontal scroll bar?

In a situation where I'm printing a string with hundreds of characters, I would like it to be able to wrap around the output window properly.

There is an editor word wrap setting but I have not been able to find anything that actually affects the output window.

Comment: No i don't think thats possible.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780497/how-do-i-turn-on-word-wrap-for-output-window-in-vs-code/77869705#77869705