# Debugging code on Azure compute - word wrap

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode using Jupyter like code cells described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py).  Works great!  The output in the "Interactive" window does not have word wrap enabled.  What do I need to set in `settings.json` to enable that?  I saw one of the other posts ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780497/how-do-i-turn-on-word-wrap-for-output-window-in-vs-code)) recommending `"[Log]": { "editor.wordWrap": "on" }` which does not help here.